# Get snapshot key from Firebase in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my Firebase database looks like:

[image]

I want to get the names "Attack on Nibeiwa", "Fort Capuzzo" and so on instead of the rest of the things. My current code gives my the complete JSON:

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Battle Details")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap : DataSnapshot)  in

        print("\(String(describing: snap.value))")


    }) { (err: Error) in


        print("\(err.localizedDescription)")

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To retrieve the names try the following:

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Battle Details")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap : DataSnapshot)  in
        for child in snap.children {
            let key = (child as AnyObject).key as String
        }
    }) { (err: Error) in
        print("\(err.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Here the snapshot is at `Battle Details` then you iterate inside the direct children which are the names in this case and retrieve the names using `child.key`